# Difference between recency & viewedByMeTime sort keys

Tags: google-drive-api

What is the difference between recency & viewedByMeTime sort keys in the orderBy parameter of a file's list api

I wanted to get the most recently accessed files through the file's list api. I tried doing so by using recency desc in the orderBy parameter. Although the document suggests that there are mutiple keys based on which the sorting can be done, so what is the difference between recency & viewedByMeTime?
Is viewedByMeTime designed to be used in the context of shared drive?